# How could spoken entries through an assistant be captured in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-docs, actions-on-google

I've been searching [actions on google data logging, spreadsheet, recording data, etc] and haven't found how to connect the assistant to Google Docs.  Is this just not possible yet?  The goal is to replace patient care sheets with spoken updates that are date and time stamped as they get added to the spreadsheet.  On the back end spreadsheet tools will be used to search and report on the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to "connect" the Assistant to a Google Sheet. This isn't a feature that is built-in to the Assistant, just like there is no way to automatically log things from your desktop or a website to a Google Sheet.

Fortunately, Google provides a developer environment for the Assistant known as [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) and [various](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) [APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) for Google Sheets. You can use these tools to make an Action that records things to a sheet the way you'd like.

There is at least one action that already does so - [Vodo Drive](https://vodo-drive.com/).